# Unfocusable JavaFX Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, javafx, window

I'm currently developing an application in JavaFX to create a **virtual keyboard**.
I had done it in Swing, and I worked with an unfocused JFrame to be able to send `KeyEvent` to the background application (for example Word is open, my always on top JFrame is visible, I click on a button, and it fire key event to Word).

In **Swing** I did:

```
frame.setFocusable(false);
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

But in **JavaFX** I didn't find how to do it, I saw

```
stage.setFocused(false);
```

But it's not working, is there an **solution** or workaround ?

Comment: `stage.setFocused()` is a deprecated method. Do you want to keep your stage always on top of other windows?

Comment: Yes I known that it's a deprecated method, but I tried it to see if it do the job, but it's not. And yes I want to keep my stage on the top, but I already know how to do it (with `setAlwaysOnTop(..)` as in Swing).
My real problem is the focus on the stage, if you don't understand what I mean, try the default virtual keyboard for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Requested a feature on report board
https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40494?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels